# How to save a Text/document file to specific folder using MemoryStream in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, save, memorystream

I have a file path from Sharepoint Document Library. The FileStrem contains the stream bytes of file from server. Now i want to `Save file` from these bytes using MemoryStream to specific folder using C# in asp.net.

```
public byte[] FileStream { get; set; }
```

**Below code i am using to save the Image File from sharepoint. It works!**

```
MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(analystPhotoObj.FileStream);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(mStream);
bitmap.Save(path + @"\MemberPhoto\" + analystPhotoObj.DocumentID + "." + analystPhotoObj.FileType);
```

Now the same thing i want to do for saving the **text/document** file.Only the thing is the  **FILE TYPE** is being changed  from *BITMA*P to *TEXT/DOCUMENT* file

Help appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the second param of bitmap.Save:

Save(Stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

Comment: i want to save text file not Image file!

Comment: you say the file type is being changed from Bitmap to Text/Document, if you say you are uploading a txt file isn't that okay then?